# Can we take liquids in transit at Doha

Tags: transit, airport-security, duty-free, doha

We are travelling to Hongkong via Doha. If we buy liquids duty free in Manchester will we be allowed to take these through Doha or is the 100ml rule in place

Answer (score 8):

You have to go through security in Doha. You CAN bring duty free liquids > 100ml BUT they must be sealed in special plastic bag called called STEB. Make sure that Manchester duty free can pack them that way before you buy.

From

https://dohahamadairport.com/airport-guide/at-the-airport/security-customs

> All the LAGs (Liquids, Aerosols and Gels) bought at Duty free shops in the airports other than HIA, in packages of more than 100 ml, must be sealed in a STEB (Security tamper-evident bag) with a receipt, as a proof of purchase. If not packed properly, all those LAGs will be confiscated by the authorities.

Comment: (+1) Does that apply to alcoholic beverages too?

Comment: @Traveller Yes. Again, presuming they are in the correct type of bag, AND you do not need to enter the country for any reason.  If you attempt to enter the country, it will be confiscated.

Comment: The linked page says that it is possible to deposit alcohol with customs if you do enter Qatar, and that you can collect it when you leave.